# How to reduce the gap between titles in page title strip in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, page-title

I am using PageTitleStrip as page swiper, i need to reduce the gap between page titles.
    Please help me out.
Suggestion appreciated.
    Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using method `setTextSpacing`. I tried -ve integer, seems to work.